# What is the "click()" element in this scenario?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

There is a switch-on/switch-off element on a Web Page. And underneath, here is the source code defined:

```
<div class = "button">
  <label class = "switch">
    <input id="sim-switch" class = "hidden" type="checkbox">
       <div class = "slider clearfix">
           ::before
           <div class="on-text pull-left">ON</div>
           <div class="off-text pull-left">OFF<div>
           <div class="inner-slider"></div>
           ::after
       </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

And if was to put this step into selenium automation, I am not sure which part is the "click()" area to make this switch happen. Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the code you posted. There's a label element wrapping a hidden checkbox and a div that (using styling) appears as a switch. Just set the checkbox to the checked (or unchecked) state.

Comment: In this case, what would the xpath setting look like, I have tried several ways, and they have been totally ignored.

Comment: Any ideas ?  I am kind of blocked here. Thanks.

Comment: @user3595231 Share your `tried several ways` please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use checkbox for operation, first locate element and use the **`isChecked()`** method with `if else` conditions for operations:

```
 WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.id("sim-switch"));
 if(ele.isSelected()==true)
 {
     System.out.println("it is clicked");
     //append your operations
 }
 else
 {
     ele.click();
     System.out.println("it is now clicked");
     //append your operations
 }
```